# js file not getting attached to html in spring boot

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot

`FILE not FOUND` error when attaching a js file to html in spring boot.
Tried calling it with all possible conventions.

Any help is appreciated.

**HTML CODE**

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
   <head>
    <title>TRYING</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script  src="why.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
     <h1>Hi world.</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Do ask if more clarity is needed.

**FILE STRUCTURE** image attached below

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a directory
>   called /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in
>   the classpath

So if you move the `why.js` to a folder named `static` in `src/main/resources` it should work.
The `templates` folder is for the `thymeleaf` templates. Js files are static content.

Answer (score 0):

> Follow the given structure to create fat jar **:**

```
Demo
└── src
|    ├── main
|    │   ├── java
|    │   │     └── org
|    │   │          └── demo
|    │   │                └── App.java
|    │   └── resources
|    |       |
|    │       └── application.properties
|    |       |
|    |       └── META-INF
|    |       |        └── resources
|    |       |                 └── jsp
|    |       └── static
|    |              └── css
|    |              └── js
|    |    
|    └── test
|         └── java
|               └── org
|                    └── demo
|                          └── App.java  
├──── pom.xml
```

> Access js and css file in html code as follow **:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/xxx.css">

<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/xxx.js"></script>
```